# What is the difference between qualified and unqualified name lookup when deducting templates?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, name-lookup

While writing template methods, i ran into the folowing behavior, which i do not understand.

I have the folowing code:

```js
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    template<typename T>
    class Bar
    {
            T Var;
    };
}

namespace B
{

    template<typename T>
    void Foo(const T& var)
    {
            std::cout << "default template method has been called" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T, size_t N>
    void Foo(const std::array<T,N>& var)
    {
            std::cout << "Array overload has been called" << std::endl;
            for(auto& elem : var)
            {
                Foo(elem);
            }
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Foo(const A::Bar<T>& var)
    {
            std::cout << "Bar overload has been called" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int                        VarInt;
    A::Bar<int>                VarBar;
    std::array<int, 1>         ArrayInt;
    std::array<A::Bar<int>, 1> ArrayBar;

    B::Foo(VarInt);
    B::Foo(VarBar);
    B::Foo(ArrayInt);
    B::Foo(ArrayBar);
    return 0;
}
```

It's output is not what i expect as with the array of Bar, the default template is called instead of the Bar overload:

```
default template method has been called

Bar overload has been called

Array overload has been called
default template method has been called

Array overload has been called
default template method has been called
```

I noticed that doing the folowing enables the compiler to find the correct overloads :

- removing all namespaces or
- declaring all the templates prototypes before implementing them

Comment: You'll get the behavior you'd expect by moving `Foo(Bar)` in namespace `A` or by moving it above `Foo(std::array)`.

Comment: Yes, that is true, however, while this is possible within this example (which of course is much simpler that what i'm working with), it is impractical to do in the real case. I'd rather use the solution of declaring overloads before implementing them.

Comment: @J.M Yes, declaration before implementation is what i'd also prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's output is not what i expect as with the **array of Bar**, the default template is called instead of the Bar overload

For the call expression, `B::Foo(ArrayBar)`, the 2nd overload `void Foo(const std::array<T,N>& var)` is chosen with `N` deduced to `1` and `T` deduced to `A::Bar<int>`.

Now inside that overload, when the call expression `Foo(elem)` is encountered, the compiler doesn't know about the third overloaded `Foo`. Thus it chooses the first overload of `Foo` which is the most general among the two available at that point.

---

> declaring all the templates prototypes before implementing them

Providing the declarations for all the overloads of `Foo` before implementing them, lets the compiler know that there is a third overload of `Foo`. So this time, the call expression `Foo(elem)` calls the third overloaded `Foo` as expected(because it is more special than the first overload of `Foo`).

---

> removing all namespaces

And when everything is put in the same global namespace, due to [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) the third overload is also found.

Comment: Why does `Foo(Bar)` get called when everything is in the global namespace? Is it because `Foo(Bar)` and `Bar` are in the same namespace so ADL finds it?

Comment: @paolo Basically yes due to ADL.

Comment: Right, when a dependent function call like `Foo(elem)` is eligible for ADL, the candidate functions are the declarations visible from the template definition plus the ones found by ADL. But for the argument type `A::Bar<int>`, ADL doesn't look in namespace `B`.